Generalized hypergeometric function and limit
And help with this monster.
$$\lim_{m\to \infty}\left[\frac{(2n+2)!(-1)^m(-1)^n(x^2)^m}{2(2m+2)!(m-n)(x^2)^n} \\ _{2}F_{3}\left(\ 1,m-n;\ m-n+1,m+\frac{3}{2},\\m+2;\frac{-x^2}{4}\right)\right]$$
I am trying to calculate this insane looking expression. It seems that the limit tends to zero and thats what i want to prove but finding an expression would be good too. First of all, x is a real number bounded in the closed interval [0,b] where b is a really large real number that you shouldn't worry about. Next n is a positive integer always less than m that cannot be bounded it should run all positive integers. Also the $\ _{2}F_{3}$ is the generalized hypergeometric function. Since the fraction before the hypergeometric function, as m tends to infinity, it tends to zero its pointless to write and my problem is with the hypergeometric function (i just included the fraction if it helps or it has important information). About the hypergeometric function my thoughts were to write it as a sum and calculate the limit of that sum but in order for the limit to go inside the sum i have to show that the sum is uniformly convergent wich seems impossible. A similar, but more easy one, i did by showing that the sum is non negative and that the limit is non positive so all in all the limit is zero. In conclusion is there a way to calculate the limit of the hypergeometric function without bounding n?

Well i just solve my question using the same way i did with the easier one. I just started with an euler's integral transform for the hypergeometric function. Then using two simple identities $\ (-1)^k≤1$ for all k integers and (k!)(a!)≤(a+k)! i concluded that the limit is non positive. After that, i broke the sum from the transformation into 2k and 2k+1 terms and then proved that the function inside the sum is positive so the sum is positive and all in all after some basic algebra we conclude that the limit is zero. Please correct if i made any errors
